# How to link to external link ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to link to an external site by doing the following:

```
<%= link_to 'My Link', @link.url %>
```

What I get when I click 'My Link' is something like:

```
http://localhost:3000/links/www.facebook.com
```

What can I do to make this a external link `www.facebook.com`?

Comment: Don't use a relative link?

Answer (score 4):

Seems like you saved your `url` without the protocol in the database (`www.facebook.com`), so they are being interpreted as relative URLs. Try specifying the protocol.

```
link_to 'My Link', "https://#{@link.url}"
```

This should solve your current problem.

But, a better approach would be to save the `url` with their protocol in the database in the first place.

So, save the `url` as `https://www.facebook.com` instead of `www.facebook.com`.

***Addition tip***: If you want your external link to open in a new browser window, use `:target => '_blank'`:

```
link_to 'My Link', "https://#{@link.url}", :target => '_blank'
```

Comment: Mike, did my answer help? Let me know if you have any other question.